# Can you assign a Masked area (in the Sculpt mode) as a Vertex group?

Tags: sculpting, vertex-groups

Watching a ZBrush tute, a guy uses a mask to block in an area and then deletes the rest of the mesh (keeping only Front faces of the Masked area)..

https://youtu.be/7wjK4axInhc?t=8m25s

That would be an amazing workflow for Blender... do you think it is possible? Maybe if I could assign the Masked area as a Vertex group?

Cheers for checking...

Comment: Perhaps you will find what you need here in the sculpt tools addon http://jayanam.com/blender-sculpt-tools-ui-mask-extract/

Comment: If it works for you, maybe include a rundown of how you used the addon to get your result and maybe a screenshot or two. That way it serves as an answer for the next person.